# 'int' object not subsriptable inside lambda function

Tags: python-3.x

I am working on a programming challenge from Hackerrank and I am getting an error 'int' object is not subscriptable. You can find the coding challenge here: https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/picking-numbers/problem. I see the similar posts on stack with same error but the answers could not help me enough to understand how to apply the same solution in my program. I am newbie in Python. Here is the code:

```
#!/bin/python3

import math
import os
import random
import re
import sys
from collections import Counter
from functools import reduce
# Complete the pickingNumbers function below.
def pickingNumbers(a):

        return (reduce(lambda y, x:max(a[x] + a[x + 1], y), range(100), -1))
if __name__ == '__main__':
    fptr = open(os.environ['OUTPUT_PATH'], 'w')

    n = int(input())

    a = Counter(map(int, input().rstrip().split()))

    result = pickingNumbers(a[n])

    fptr.write(str(result) + '\n')

    fptr.close()
```

Here is the error I am getting:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "solution.py", line 21, in <module>
    result = pickingNumbers(a[n])
  File "solution.py", line 13, in pickingNumbers
    return (reduce(lambda y, x:max(a[x] + a[x + 1], y), range(100), -1))
  File "solution.py", line 13, in <lambda>
    return (reduce(lambda y, x:max(a[x] + a[x + 1], y), range(100), -1))
TypeError: 'int' object is not subscriptable
```

Comment: It means that your `a` is an integer, and `a[something]` means nothing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You error means that you are trying to subscriptable an integer like `24[0]` which isn't correct.

In your code you are doing :

```
a = Counter(map(int, input().rstrip().split()))
result = pickingNumbers(a[n])
```

Where `a[n]` is a number. As I said, in your function you are doing `a[x] + a[x + 1]` which means nothing to a number. Perhaps you want to send the the `Counter` => `pickingNumbers(a)`

Comment: Thanks @Hearner. I changed the calling statement from pickingNumbers(a[n]) to pickingNumbers(a) and that worked. Thanks for the hint

Answer (score 1):

In lambda, `a` is an int (because you are calling this function not with array, but with int), so you cannot access x'th element of it. You should probably change line:

`result = pickingNumbers(a[n])`

to:

`result = pickingNumbers(a)`

Answer (score 0):

```
def pickingNumbers(a):
    b = list()
    tempSum = pairSum = 0
    a.sort(reverse=True)
    c = sorted(set(a),reverse=True)
    for sortNum in c:
        b.append([a.count(sortNum), sortNum])
    b.sort(key= lambda x:x[1], reverse=True)
    for left in b:
        for right in b:
            if abs(left[1] - right[1]) <= 1 and left != right:
                tempSum = left[0] + right[0]
                if tempSum > pairSum:
                    pairSum = tempSum
    if pairSum > max(b)[0]:
        return(pairSum)
    else:
        return(max(b)[0])

if __name__ == '__main__':
    n = int(input().strip())
    a = list(map(int, input().rstrip().split()))
    result = pickingNumbers(a)
    print(str(result) + '\n')
```

[I have explained the working of the code here](https://medium.com/@PeaceOfury/picking-numbers-3c48e07604e8?source=friends_link&sk=e32385e0693ad011c53f2d420c520fc3)